# How to change the order of the three vectors that are dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

Two vectors: $u$ (a unit vector) and $x$ (a regular non-unit vector), the angle between them is $\theta$

I want to know the derivation process of changing $(x\cdot u)u$ to ***x (intuitively, I want to move $x$ to the far right side, and the `***`is any proper form that makes it work).

One of the appealing reasons to do that is that I can use *** as an operation on vector x.

But here, does anyone could help me out for how to derive it from  $(x\cdot u)u$u to ***x ?

Note that $u(u\cdot x)$ is not what we want, there should be no parenthesis.

Comment: $u \cdot u \cdot x$ does not make sense for general vectors.  A single dot product will give you a scalar.  A scalar dotted with another vector may not be well-defined.

Comment: I edit the post, such that it won't confuse you. From my point of view, a scalar dot a vector is simply stretching the length of the vector along its original direction.

Comment: Could you define $(x.u)$. Is it equivalent to $x^T u$?

Comment: @Dunkel Hi, I think you are right.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If so, $ k= x^T u$ will be a scalar. Thus, you will have $k u$ (scaled version of $u$). As a consequence, you cannot compute the inverse of a vector $k u$, as it is not defined.

Comment: @Dunkel Thanks for explaining that, you are right. Actually what I originally want is whatever *** is, and see it as an operation on x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define $ (x \cdot u) = x^T u $, then $ (x \cdot u) u = (x^T u) u = k u$. However, note that $ k = x^T u $ is a scalar. Equivalently, $ k = u^T x $.

$$ 
(x \cdot u) u = k u 
$$.

Since $k$ is an scalar we can exchange the positions of $k$ and $u$. Then, 
$$ (x \cdot u) u = u k = u (u^T x) $$

Finally

$$
(x \cdot u) u = P x
$$
where $ P = u u^T $ is a matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's the key insight that you use ${ u }^{ T }x$ to replace $x\cdot u$, because this gives us the chance to get rid off the parenthesis without worrying about against any rules like the situation we have for $u(u\cdot x)$

Comment: Can you explain to me why we can say that $u(u^T x) = Px$ where $P=u u^T$? Is it correct to multiply $u$ with $u^T$ first even though the parenthesis indicates that we should multiply $u^T$ with $x$ first?

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible.  $(x \cdot u)u$ is a scalar multiple of $u$, and you can't write it as a multiple of $x$ unless $x$ is a multiple of $u$.

For instance, let $u=i$ and $x=i+j$.  Then $(x \cdot u)u = i$, and you can't write $i$ as a multiple of $i+j$.

Also, scalar multiplication by a vector is not a one-to-one operation, so “canceling” a dot product or multiplying by an inverse to a vector is undefined.

Comment: Then *** should be in a form of matrix that will be given by any info available from u or x, right?

When "canceling", if only scalar is left in the equation, then it is what it is. I don't see anything wrong with it. What is left such that we could say it makes sense?

Comment: @Jason: If $\alpha x = \beta x$ for scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and a vector $x$, then yes, $\alpha = \beta$.  But if $u \cdot x = v \cdot x$, you can't conclude that $u=v$.  I wasn't sure which of those equations you were thinking of when you said “multiply by the inverse of $x$.”

Comment: I see what confuses you. I change the language in the question description such that I won't have inverse. What I want essentially is just *** that could be regarded as an operation on vector x. To be able to do that, it requires x to be on the far right side.

Comment: Oh, now I finally understand your question.  If that is what you want, then Dunkel's answer is the right one.

Comment: @Mathew Leingang I was changing the language as you guys come up with new confusion, such that the question is bit more clear now lol

Comment: A lesson in the importance of asking a precise question.

Answer (score 0):

Using Einstein notation:
\begin{align}
((x \cdot u)u)_i
&=x_ju_ju_i\\
&=u_iu_jx_j\\
&=P_{ij}x_j\\
&=(Px)_i
\end{align}
So we have that
$$(x \cdot u)u = Px$$
If we define the $P$ matrix as $P_{ij}=u_iu_j$. Note that because $u$ is an unit vector, $P$ will be the projection matrix to $u$.

Comment: Does $u_i u_j$ mean $uu^T$?

Comment: Yes, $a_i b_j$ is the $i,j$-th component of the $a b^T$ matrix.